# How to merge several zip files in one zip file in HDFS hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, zip

I am running a mapreduce job that create several zip files for each row key .
I am not able to create one zip files for all records .So is there any way to merge several all zip files in a single zip files in hadoop mapreduce .
This is how i create zip files for each row-key

```
@Override
        public void write(K key, V value) throws IOException {
            final String valueStr = value.toString();
            String strFullFileName[] = valueStr.split("\\|\\^\\|");
            String strKey = strFullFileName[0] + strFullFileName[1];

            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(strKey);
            zipOut.closeEntry();
            zipOut.putNextEntry(ze);

            if (value instanceof BytesWritable) {
                zipOut.write(((BytesWritable) value).getBytes(), 0,
                        ((BytesWritable) value).getLength());
            } else {
                zipOut.write(value.toString().getBytes());
            }

        }
```

Can we merge several zip files in mapreduce it self if not please suggest a command to merge .

Comment: is that a method of a custom writable class?

Comment: @vefthym yes it is ..